# Приложение занимает слишком много ОЗУ

Tags: visual-studio, память, c++-cli, clr

Суть в том, что во время события MouseMove приложение в ОЗУ начинает занимать 1ГБ и больше, и даже после окончания этого события продолжает занимать столько места. Что и как можно подправить? Моя программа рисует линии и прямоугольники, поверх изображения, а так же вырезает и сохраняет в picturebox фрагмент.

```
static      Point^ pointstart = gcnew Point(0,0);
static      array<Point>^ Points = gcnew array<Point>(100000);
static          int i=1, j=0, proverka=0, xs, ys, xe, ye;
static          array<Bitmap^>^ reserv=gcnew array<Bitmap^>(100);
private: System::Void picture_MouseMove(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
     {
         if (proverka!=0)
         {
            if (type == 1 || type == 3)
            {
                picture->Image = reserv[j-1];
                xe=Convert::ToInt32(e->X);
                ye=Convert::ToInt32(e->Y);
                pointstart->X = Convert::ToInt64(e->X);
                pointstart->Y = Convert::ToInt64(e->Y);
                Points-> SetValue (pointstart, i);
                if (i!=1)
                {
                    Bitmap^ pic = gcnew Bitmap (picture->Image);
                    Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pic);
                    array<Point>^ PointsDraw = gcnew array<Point>(i);
                    Array::Copy(Points, PointsDraw, i);
                    g->DrawCurve(newpen, PointsDraw);
                    picture->Image = pic;
                    Array::Clear(PointsDraw, 0, i);
                }
                xs=xe;
                ys=ye;
                i++;
            }
            if (type == 2 || type == 4)
            {
                 picture->Image = reserv[j-1];
                 int xw, yw;
                 xe=Convert::ToInt32(e->X);
                 ye=Convert::ToInt32(e->Y);
                 if (xs < xe && ys < ye )
                 {
                     xw = xe - xs;
                     yw = ye - ys;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    xw = xe - xs;
                    yw = ye - ys;
                    xs = xe;
                    ys = ye;
                 }
                 Bitmap^ pic = gcnew Bitmap (picture->Image);
                 Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pic);
                 g->DrawRectangle(newpen, xs, ys, abs(xw), abs(yw));
                 picture->Image = pic;
             }
         }
      }
private: System::Void picture_MouseUp(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
     {
         if (proverka!=0)
         {
             if (type == 1 || type == 3)
             {
                picture->Image = reserv[j-1];
                //Задание точек
                pointstart->X = Convert::ToInt64(e->X);
                pointstart->Y = Convert::ToInt64(e->Y);
                Points-> SetValue (pointstart, i);
                array<Point>^ PointsDraw = gcnew array<Point>(i);
                Array::Copy(Points, PointsDraw, i);
                //Рисование
                Bitmap^ pic = gcnew Bitmap(picture->Image);
                Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pic);
                g->DrawCurve(newpen, PointsDraw);
                picture->Image = pic;
                //Сохранение
                reserv->SetValue (pic, j);
                j++;
                //Возвращение к начальным значениям
                Array::Clear(Points, 0, Points->Length);
                Array::Clear(PointsDraw, 0, i);
                i=1;
                proverka=0;
             }
             if (type == 2)
             {
                 picture->Image = reserv[j-1];
                 int xw, yw;
                 xe=Convert::ToInt32(e->X);
                 ye=Convert::ToInt32(e->Y);
                 if (xs < xe && ys < ye )
                 {
                     xw = xe - xs;
                     yw = ye - ys;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    xw = xe - xs;
                    yw = ye - ys;
                    xs = xe;
                    ys = ye;
                 }
                 Bitmap^ pic = gcnew Bitmap (picture->Image);
                 Graphics^ g = Graphics::FromImage(pic);
                 g->DrawRectangle(newpen, xs, ys, abs(xw), abs(yw));
                 picture->Image = pic;
                 //Сохранение
                 reserv->SetValue (pic, j);
                 j++;
                 //К начальным данным
                 proverka = 0;
                 i=1;

             }
             if (type == 4)
             {
                 picture->Image = reserv[j-1];
                 int xw, yw;
                 xe=Convert::ToInt32(e->X);
                 ye=Convert::ToInt32(e->Y);
                 if (xs < xe && ys < ye )
                 {
                     xw = xe - xs;
                     yw = ye - ys;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                    xw = xe - xs;
                    yw = ye - ys;
                    xs = xe;
                    ys = ye;
                 }
                 Bitmap^ pic = gcnew Bitmap(picture->Image);
                 Rectangle cloneRect = Rectangle(xs, ys, xw, yw);
                 picture->Image = pic->Clone(cloneRect, pic->PixelFormat);
                 Bitmap^ save = gcnew Bitmap(picture->Image);
                 reserv->SetValue (save, j);
                 j++;

             }
          }
     }
```

Comment: ну, а что Вы ожидали? судя по коду, Вы заводите массив на 100 картинок. Если даже каждая картинка будет 640х480, то это уже больше 100 мб. Это если не считать накладных расходов.

кстати, 

    static int i=1, j=0;
    static array<Bitmap^>^ reserv=gcnew array<Bitmap^>(100);

вызывают шок. Первая строка - никто так i и j не использует. Нужны более понятные имена.
вторая - думаю, стоит заменить на что то вида

    stack<Bitmap^>^ reserv = gcnew stack<Bitmap^>();

а там выясниться, что и переменная j не нужна.

Comment: Про стек, спасибо! На счет i, j учту)Но вот проблема возникает во время рисования, когда начинаю рисовать ОЗУ просто улетает.

Comment: конечно будет улетать. `picture_MouseMove` вызывается очень часто. Как минимум раз 10 в секунду. если `proverka` не равно нулю, то за секунд 10 "шевеления мышкой" массив будет под завязку.

Comment: Но, при рисовании прямоугольника, массивы не используются, а память уходит.